# What are the differences between jQuery polling and the Faye server?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, polling

I encountered both the [faye server](http://railscasts.com/episodes/260-messaging-with-faye) and [jQuery polling](http://railscasts.com/episodes/229-polling-for-changes) in those two railscasts. It seems to me that they are two different techniques that ultimately accomplish the same thing. When would you want to choose one over the other? What are the relative advantages/disadvantages of each?

Answer (score 2):

Faye is more complex and solid solution. Looks like it using sockets for messaging, while jQuery polling is just sending ajax requests through time intervals

Comment: With faye you get the message immediately after it was posted. With polling you get all the messages in time intervals.

Comment: so Faye is more immediate, but does that mean that polling would put less strain on servers?

Comment: Depends what you mean by strain - Faye ought to result in less processing, but will lead to more open connections.

Answer (score 0):

The way Faye does it is better than polling, since the server can know the client to which send a message just when the server receives the messages, whereas polling you would have to do requests every amount of time to see if there is a new message on the server and show it to the client.

So for a message, you would probably make more than one request, while with web sockets the server makes a request. Also, for using faye you would need another server to handle the connections within the server and all the clients.